# Year so yearly, hour so hourly but then what for minute and second?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

Suppose I have software that generates a report every year. So, what I get is a yearly report. Likewise. . . Weekly report and hourly report.

What can we use for the report generated every minute? And every second? Minutely? Secondly? :-D

Looking for those two adverbs that shouldn't mean microscopically and at second place respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any adverbs that will fit the bill. I think your best bet would be to use "every minute" or "on a (per) minute basis." The same would go for seconds.

Comment: "Every minute" and "Every second" sound the most natural.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any adjective for minute or second that corresponds to "yearly". The parallel phrase to "We produce an hourly report" would be "We produce a report every minute". You could call it a "by-the-minute report" or "to-the-minute report", or depending on context maybe a "one-minute report" or simply a "minute report".

Even if you find some word in a dictionary that means "for one minute", like "hourly", I'd guess that few people would know what it meant, so it probably wouldn't be very useful.